# ServiceStack OrmLite, Read all records

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Just trying out OrmLite for first time, and have been looking through examples/docs for like 20 min now with no luck trying to find a simple answer.

Is there a way to just return all records of a certain type?
(something that returns maybe a a List or something.

I thought'd there would be a

```
db.SelectAll<T>();
```

something similar.

I'm sure there is a really easy way besides just sending the query isn't there?

```
SELECT * FROM [TableName]
```

I'm sure i've just overlooked one of the methods, or not found the correct overload yet..but if someone could give a me a shove forward, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, the answer is `db.Select<T>();`

Comment: well...that was easy, not sure how I missed, thanks.